# Not getting the 'Zend Amf endpoint' mesage on dreamhost but OK on my localserver

Tags: php, apache-flex, apache2, zend-amf

I've been working with Zend Amf for few months and everything is fine on my localserver (and was fine on my test server hosted by dreamhost) until recently. Now every time I try to access the gateway via the URL (i.e. http://hostname/gateway/) instead of the 'Zend AMF endpoint' message should be getting, the browser simply prompts me to download an application/x-amf file.

I have checked my code for any leading or trailing spaces (made sure all my PHP didn't have an endtag). Checked the PHP version..it's 5.2..updated Zend to 1.10.7.

I was hoping that this wasn't interfering with my remote flash calls but that doesn't seem to be working as well. Flex doesn't even report a fault code.

Is there any specific PHP settings I should be checking?

Comment: Usually, when the server prompts me to download something that it should 'serve' it is due to an incorrect (or missing) mime type setting on the server.  So, my best guess is that it is a configuration error somewhere; but I'm not sure of the specifics of your current problem. You might check the web server as opposed to PHP.

Comment: Dreamhost is running Apache. I asked them the same question and they responded by asking me to add a mime type as well so I added to the .htaccess file:
"AddType application/x-amf" or "AddType application/x-amf amf" but both don't anything significant to solve things

Answer (score 0):

Not really fixed anything but my Zend AMF IS working and the prompt to download an application/x-amf file is perfectly fine. My problem was more of a database inconsistency and the fact that my OpenAuth login system broke.